# how to match only the certain number in the string and not a substring in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that looks something similar like:

```
String str = "19+28+1435+1940-211929*31231/3219";
```

I'd like to make a regex that would match only the number: **only 19** 
or only 28 or only 1435, (only the desired number and not the numbers that contain it). For example I want to match 19, I don't want 1940 to be matched or 3219 or 211929. I tried with `[\\A\\+\\-\\*\\/](d{1,3})[\\+\\-\\*\\/\\z]`
but didn't give me the desired result. 
(I decided to go with d{1,3} because the number I want to match is 1 or 2 or 3 digits)

Comment: This should work : [^\d](\d+)[^\d]

Answer (score 2):

You can use word boundaries `\b` like this:

```
\b19\b
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/FGBT0l/1)**

So, for your explicit statement *only 19 or only 28 or only 1435*, you can use:

```
\b(19|28|1435)\b
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/FGBT0l/2)**

Btw, for your other statement *the number I want to match is 1 or 2 or 3 digits*, then you can use:

```
\b\d{1,3}\b
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/FGBT0l/3)**

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `[^0-9](19|1435|28)[^0-9]`

Use the first capture group to select the number you are trying to match.